# PNPieChart percentag overlap when percentage is either too small or similar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Pie Chart from PNChart library. My problem is that when the calculated percentage is either **too small** or **similar**, the values **overlap**.

[image]

Also similar values pose problem. eg- if percentages are 2% and 3% and they are being shown in blue and red respectively, then only red shows up completely hiding 2% in blue.

[image]

Comment: It's a badly made library. So change another library.

Comment: plz suggest one. It was the only one with the highest star rating.

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts